# Scrapy crawl appends locally, replaces on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy, boto

I implemented a Scrapy project that is now working fine locally. Using the crawl command, each spider appended it's jsonlines to the same file if the file existed. When I changed the feed exporter to S3 using boto it now overwrites the entire file with the data from the last run spider instead of appending to the file.

Is there any way to enable the Scrapy/boto/S3 to append the jsonlines in to the file like it does locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to append to a file in S3.  You could enable versioning on the S3 bucket and then each time the file was written to S3, it would create a new version of the file.  Then you could retrieve all versions of the file using the [list_versions](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list_versions) method of the boto Bucket object.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the feed exporter code (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/feedexport.py), the file exporter opens the specified file in append mode whilst the S3 exporter calls `set_contents_from_file` which presumably overwrites the original file.

The boto S3 documentation (http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) doesn't mention being able to modify stored files, so the only solution would be to create a custom exporter that stores a local copy of results that can be appended to first before copying that file to S3.